# Google Apps Script Make Button that Runs Function with Multiple Parameters

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I have created a button in the sidebar and when the user clicks the button I would like it to run a function that has multiple parameters (these parameters change and are not constant, so can't be hard coded into the html.

My `HTML` code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <style type="text/css">
    button { 
      font-size: 13px;
      margin:5px;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button class="button" style="background-color:#cfe2f3ff;" onclick="google.script.run.setupOffice()">Setup/Reset</button>
</body>
</html>
```

The function I am trying to run upon the button being clicked is very long. But it looks like this to give you an idea:

```
function setupOffice(officeSelection, ss, officeID){}
```

The `officeSelection` parameter is based on what the user has selected from a dropdown in a certain cell (A2). `ss` is just calling a specific sheet by name. `officeID` is calling an array that is compared to `officeSelection`.

Is there a way I can get the button to just function the same as when I draw an image and assign a script to it?

Thanks!

Comment: @TheMaster I am not sure how I would do that?

Comment: How would you  assign a script to image and still expect to pass params?

Comment: Call a another function say `main`, which will call `setupOffice()` with it's parameters.

Comment: Or use UI prompt in the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function runWithButtonAndSupplyParamsAtRunTime() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const resp=SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt("Enter Parameters","Enter param1/param2/param3/param4....",SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  if(resp.getSelectedButton()==SpreadsheetApp.getUi().Button.OK) {
    let param=resp.getResponseText().split('/');
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(param.join('\n'));//just to view params
    //now your params are in param[0],param[1]....
    //do the rest of your work here
  }else{
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('No parameters provide');
  }
}
```